# Dynamically showing large amount of html through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to find the most reasonable way to dynamically show a **lot** of HTML after an AJAX call. We currently get a json array and then just create a string of HTML including the array values, then spit that all to $("#ele").html(), but the string is huge.

And that's the concern; we've got a good 100 lines of `<div>`s and `<spans>`, etc. in a javascript variable, Which makes the jquery string to dynamically insert a new order entry big and ugly, like below:

```
var newEntry = "<div class='sale-box' id='saleBox"+respObj[i]["id"]+"'>"
                                +"<div style='width: 100%; float: left;'>"
                                    +"<b><center>Invoice Number "+respObj[i]["invoiceNumber"]+"</b>"
                                    +"<a href='https://www.bluescentric.com/mgmt/log-entries.php?i="+respObj[i]["id"]+"'>"
                                    +" <i>(See History Log)</i></a></center>"
                +a hundred more lines... literally.
```

Is there a better way to display a large amount of HTML from javascript? Right now, it seems our two options are 1) just having the php create the whole "" structure and sending that to javascript, or 2) taking the array variables and plug them into a big, long javascript string that we then output to an element?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Comment: You will need to use a framework or something to transform the json into html. Take a look at this http://json2html.com/

Comment: Are you having an actual/specific problem? Or are you just trying to clean things up?

Comment: Well, I suppose I'm looking to clean things up, but I feel like the execution we've got now is prone to a lot of problems, (like if we change the template, we gotta change the JS string) etc. and I feel like there's probably a better solution out there that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Personally I would use PHP to retrieve an html file contents and spit that back out for javascript to use as a template.  I would probably use a syntax like "<center>Invoice Number {{invoice_number}}</center>" and something like template.interpolate({'invoice_number':13323})

So that way you have a separate file to change the html, it's clean and using {{variable_names}} for holders that javascript would use for variable interpolation.

Comment: @Xiquid that is an EXCELLENT suggestion. That might be an ideal kind of answer. One template that can be easily changed in one file.

Answer (score 1):

Use a templating system or create a simple template system.  Use the function `get_file_contents` of an html file that contains something like this:

```
<table><tr><td>{{column_1}}</td><td>{{column_2}}</td></table>
```

And then use javascript as an ajax request to retrieve the file and use something like

```
var template = "string of template from php";
var interpolated_template = template.interpolate({column_1:'something',column_2:'something2'});
```

`interpolate` is a `String.prototype.interpolate = function ...` prototype function extending String, so any string can interpolate variables using the syntax `"String".interpolate(args_as_object)`

:-)